# Dynamic function calling Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic-function

I have function name in a variable and I am assigning that variable on click event of button. but it is not working. Any Help?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
    <h2>Function name is: {{FunctionName}}</h2>
    <input type="button" value="click here" (click) = [FunctionName]()>
    </div>
    <p>{{value}}</p>
  `,
})
export class App {
  FunctionName:string;
  value: string;
  constructor() {
    this.FunctionName = 'clickFunction'
  }

  clickFunction(){
    this.value = "button clicked";
  }
}
```

Here is the code

[Plunker Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/kVguXrPQ1V9y45HjXenI?p=info)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Syntax needs to be like this:

```
<input type="button" value="click here" (click) ="this[FunctionName]()">
```

Fixed plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/xGgFQuHNH72Q9FdOPEdK?p=preview

Comment: Is it possible if I do the same with child-parent related component. Like I write (click) = "this....." on child components selector. and define the function on parent component's ts file. will it work?

Comment: @amansoni211 but the child components template scope will be out of the parents scope. I don't think that will work.

Comment: Will this work if I define this function in parent component? call it in childs template like we are doing above.

Comment: @amansoni211 isn't it the same thing with your previous comment? Create a new question about it maybe with a clear usage?

Comment: What if the event name is also dynamic and coming from json variable. how I can make this dynamic clickFunction(){
    this.value = "button clicked";
  }
my function name is coming from json file

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers then bind that json variable to `this.value`? Are you getting the json file via an http when an async operation happens? Can you give more context?

Comment: @eko - Yes, I am getting from http function, but again it is fine if you take as static variable. but the problem is FUNCTION name should be dynamic as per json property, so even If i change json property value, it works

Comment: @eko- you can refer this link, I created separate stack for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56868659/how-to-create-function-name-from-json-in-angular-7/56868700?noredirect=1#comment100288196_56868700

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Function name is: {{FunctionName}}</h2>
      <input type="button" value="click here" (click)="FunctionName()">
    </div>
    <p>{{value}}</p>
  `,
})
export class App {
  FunctionName: Fn;
  value: string;
  constructor() {
    this.FunctionName = this.clickFunction; //assign function to variable.
  }

  clickFunction(){
    this.value = "button clicked";
  }
}
```

Online demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/6uVZd0L0KlwMdaIKgPXq?p=preview