# How to create function name from json in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I have to create dynamic button from json file. My JSON is as per below:

```
{ button : { title : "Submit", event : "FunctionName", color : "white".... }}
```

My Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
    <h2>Function name is: {{FunctionName}}</h2>
    <input type="button" value="click here" (click)="this[FunctionName]()">
    </div>
    <p>{{value}}</p>
  `,
})

export class App {
  FunctionName:string;
  value: string;
  constructor() {
    this.FunctionName = button.FunctionName;
  }

  Button.FunctionName(){ //<-----How can I give name from JSON
    this.value = "button clicked";
  }
}
```

> My function name is coming from JSON file. so How can I create such
>   function in my TS file?

Enhancement of [Dynamic function calling Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106381/dynamic-function-calling-angular-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically set a function/object name in Javascript as it is displayed in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871040/how-to-dynamically-set-a-function-object-name-in-javascript-as-it-is-displayed-i)

Comment: What problem are you **really** trying to solve here? This looks like a XY problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Nope, it isn't XY Problem. My Question is straight forward. I want to call dynamic function named as "EVENT" in json data

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
{ button : { title : "Submit", event : () => this.FunctionName(), color : "white".... }}
```

If you cannot change the json, then this might work:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="click here" (click)="callFunction(FunctionName)">
```

TS:

```
callFunction(functionName:string) {
    let comp_obj = new ClassComponent();
    comp_obj[functionName]();
}
```

From stackbiltz:  Add this in TS

```
 callFunction(FunctionName: string) {
    let x = new AppComponent();
    x[FunctionName]();
  }

  enrollmentFormProblem() {
    alert("enrollmentFormProblem called")
  }
```

HTML:

```
<button (click)="callFunction(dynamicButton[0].event)">{{this.dynamicButton[0].description}}</button>
```

To add the function dynamically with having it predefined, do this:

```
callFunction(FunctionName: string) {
    let x = new AppComponent();

    x[FunctionName] = new Function (
      console.log(`${FunctionName} created`)
    )
  }
```

Comment: I can not change value in JSON file, as it is coming from API. I can only Change in Angular code

Comment: Try this, Editted the answer. I haven't tested it though, if it doesn't work, please share a stackbiltz

Comment: will it work if I change event value to some other value without changing enrollmentFormProblem name? like if  event : "submitEvent", it will call enrollmentFormProblem event?

Comment: Whatever function name you add in the event, that function has to be present in the class. That's all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195928/discussion-between-ubiquitous-developers-and-adrita-sharma).